# Hyperfiniteness of CCR algebra

Tags: oa.operator-algebras

Hi, It is known that the double commutant of the CCR algebra in it's GNS space 
with respect to some quasi-free states are always type III factors.
My question is;  Will some of them be hyperfinite factors?

Comment: Sorry for confusing Ccr with ccr;-)

Comment: Just to pick up on Marc's comment: by CCR you mean canonical commutation relations, not completely continuous representations (aka liminal), right?

Comment: I answered that the later are alway type 1, but the op referred to the former.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Araki-Woods showed they're always ITPFI factors and ITPFI factors are hyperfinite. See the following:

[Araki-Woods, A classification of factors](http://www.ems-ph.org/journals/show_pdf.php?issn=0034-5318&vol=4&iss=1&rank=4)

It's a bit of a monster paper, the stuff on CCR algebras is near the end.